# how do I check if numbers repeat in a 3x3 grid?

Tags: python, sudoku

```
def isSudokuBox(B):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for z in range(0, 3):
            if int(B[i][z]) <= 0:

                return False
                continue
            elif int(B[i][z]) > 9:

                return False
                continue
```

So I made the part that checks if the number is from 1 to 9 and it works, but I can't figure out how to make it check for elements that exist more than once. What could I do? One way is to just make conditionals for each possible case but that's very tedious and not very beautiful. There must be another way.

An example of said array looks like this:

```
A3 = [[9,8,2],
[1,3,5],
[6,2,1]]
```

How do I make an algorithm that returns False to the function above when I pass in A3 as an argument?

Comment: "Repeating" = ?? (Example data would go a long way.)

Comment: Also, there should never be code "after" a `return` - keeping this rule can help reduce some mis-beliefs.

Comment: is using `numpy`allowed?

Comment: yes using numpy is allowed

Comment: For sudoku and 3x3 only, try this one liner `len({j for i in A3 for j in i}) == 9`

Comment: @YiFei note that this is not stable if values above 10 can be inserted in the boxes.

Comment: @pythonic833 I don't understand - works for `C = [[10,1,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]`

Comment: @ChrisCharley sure it does, but usually sudoku works with numbers from 1 to 9 and therefore it is more stable to restrict them to this range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have a `3x3` numpy array

```
import numpy as np
(np.sort(arr.reshape(-1)) == np.arange(1, 10)).all()
```

Example:

```
x_complete = np.array([[3, 5, 1],
                      [2, 4, 7],
                      [6, 8, 9]])
(np.sort(x_comp.reshape(-1)) == np.arange(1, 10)).all()
```

results in

```
True
```

While

```
x_incomplete = np.array([[3, 3, 1],
                          [2, 4, 7],
                          [6, 8, 9]])
(np.sort(x_incomplete.reshape(-1)) == np.arange(1, 10)).all()
```

is `False`

First we reshape the `3x3` array to be a 1d array. Now we can sort the array and this array can be compared with the expected array `np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])` (I just use the shorthand notation). Since we compare element-by-element so that an array of bools is returned, we check whether all elements are identical.

### numpy solution

In order to use it with the rest of your code, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
def isSudokuBox(B):
    arr = np.array(B)
    return (np.sort(arr.reshape(-1)) == np.arange(1, 10)).all()
```

### solution using reduce and built-ins

If you don't want to use numpy this can be done with

```
from functools import reduce
def isSudokuBox(B):
    return sorted(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, B)) == list(range(1,10))
```

Comment: can you explain to me what that does? I need to put it in a way so it works with the rest of the code, thank you!

Comment: I'm reaaally sorry, can you use my function names and variable names. I'm pretty confused...

Comment: hope this helps ;)

Comment: did you import numpy as np?

Comment: Oh my God! It worked! I'm going to need to review this later on. I can't believe it took me like more than 3 hours... I thought of resorting the array into a single one by printing each value then appending it to another list then using that list, check if any duplicates arise xD  This boy has learned the power of numpy!! Thanks a lot to you and all those above you for taking the time to teach me this!

Comment: This led me to an idea resulting in a solution using only the reduce function and build-ins

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have an array with 9 0's:

```
numCounts = [0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0]
```

everytime when you look at a number increment it's index. If the index becomes larger than 1 then you have a duplicate number:

```
numCounts[number]+=1
if(numCounts[number] > 1):
    print("duplicate " + str(number))


def isSudokuBox(B):
    numCounts = [0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0]
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for z in range(0, 3):
            if int(B[i][z]) <= 0:
                return False
            elif int(B[i][z]) > 9:
                return False
            # here we use the number as the index
            # -1 in order to get values from 0 to 8 which will correspond to the locations of those numbers in the array.
            numCounts[B[i][x]-1]+=1
            if(numCounts[B[i][x]-1] > 1):
                return False
   return True # if we get till the end we know that it is a Sudoku box
```

Comment: hmmm... so if I wanted to check for multiple numbers I do:

numCounts = [0,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0]

for number in range(1, 10):
          numCounts[number] += 1
          if(numCounts[number] > 1):
                      return True

Comment: @LagAttack451, I updated my answer. To include the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [[1,1,1], [4,4,4],[7,7,7]]
y = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def has_dups(ob):
    flat = [x2 for x1 in ob for x2 in x1]
    return len(flat) != len(set(flat))

print(has_dups(x))
print(has_dups(y))
```